# IDEA 13 XML editor does not show resource value after clicking on it

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a resource `@dimen/txt_size` with the value of `20`. When I open the XML layout file in the XML `Text` editor, I will notice that it shows grey-colored value "20" instead of "@dimen/txt_size". This is normal behaviour as of IDEA 13 (as I think).

Then, when **I click on the grey-colored text**, the value "20" will convert to "@dimen/txt_size" as IDEA will stop enterpreting the value. All of this goes by plan.

But how can I return to `value display` as it was the first time I opened the XML layout file?

I tried pressing ESC, clicking somewhere else, changing to another file and returning to this one... all in vain. I cannot make it display value "20" again.

Comment: So this is a bug then???

Comment: Close and open file again

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes, I know that. But it should refresh immediately, right? Also if I refresh the "aim value", it is not reflected back in the XML. Do you know where I can report this bug?

Comment: there is answer saying it is not bug. But if you think it is you can fire it here:http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @EugenMartynov Do this: When you open XML, you will see "value" instead of "tag". Click on the value and the tag will appear. Right?! Now, how do you return back to green display again (value display)? Another thing, try changing value and see if it updates? It does not, right? This is what I was talking about.

Comment: This is posted as a question but the user is just trying to report a but a functionality that he doesn't like as a bug

Comment: @zpontikas On the contrary. I did not know this is a bug or unimplemented feature before I posted it here. Why downvoting?

Comment: This is neither a bug or an unimplemented feature as you think. Its the normal functionality of the application.

Comment: @zpontikas What is normal if "app has feature of showing value instead of attribute" and the "value does not update in XML view when it's changed in the source"? This is far from normal behaviour.

Comment: It updates when its changed in my version 13.1

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a bug.
Its the default state of IntelliJ. 
What happens is that **instead** of showing you the tag **@dimen/txt_size** it resolves that tag to its actual value (**20**) when compiled/parsed.
See example bellow:
The green one is the value parsed (**sync4**)

and the red one is what is actual value that exists in the xml file **${rabbit.host}**
[image]

Comment: Do this: When you open XML, you will see "value" instead of "tag". Click on the value and the tag will appear. Right?! Now, how do you return back to green display again (value display)? Another thing, try changing value and see if it updates? It does not, right? This is what I was talking about.

Comment: Oh ok. This is simple.
All you have to do is to close the xml tab in the editor and open it again. Its quite simple I think

Comment: Again, I know this. But this should be refreshed automatically. So it's a bug indeed.

Comment: Its not a bug. Its how its implemented

Comment: I don't think it was supposed to be implemented that way. I mean auto-refresh had to be the first idea when they thought if this idea.

Comment: Well you can open a bug issue in intelliJ youtrack **[here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard)** and report it if you think its a bug :). They do look at them quite fast. All the features I asked them have been implemented :D